# What is the default cache expiration time for Firestore documents in iOS apps?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the default cache expiration time for Firestore documents in iOS apps? In other words, how long will Firestore use the cached version of a document before fetching the latest version from the server, assuming the document hasn't changed on the server?

I'm building an iOS app that uses Firestore for data storage, and I want to understand how the Firestore cache works so I can optimize my app's performance. I've searched the Firestore documentation but haven't been able to find a clear answer to this question.

and is there is a reference(documentation) speak about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit cache expiration.Cloud Firestore sets a default threshold for cache size. After exceeding the default, garbage collection process  for on-disk persistence that removes older documents is  enabled by default. The SDK will attempt to periodically clean up older, unused documents once the on-disk cache passes a threshold size (default: 100 MB  it is based on network connection also if a device getting disconnected from the network it will cache more data but when comes online it will try to revalidate the cached data with reference to actual data in Firestore db. TLDR is depends on case by case basis)

You can configure a different cache size threshold or disable the clean-up process completely.you can refer to this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size) for more information

```
// The default cache size threshold is 100 MB. Configure "cacheSizeBytes"
// for a different threshold (minimum 1 MB) or set to "FirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited"
// to disable clean-up.
let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
settings.cacheSizeBytes = FirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited
Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
```